# Not install free version application on second time on same

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have load free version app on android market.I want to that user install app only one time on devices.Not second time.How to solve this problem in android devices.

Comment: Seems like a slightly strange way of limiting access to a free app.  Are you saying that I can download your trial version on my phone, but if I for any reason lose the app off my phone I lose the trial access?  Why not just require a login, you can then manage all this from your end, more securely.

Comment: If it's free, why would you limit the users? It's my phone, I have the right to download an application and install it as many times as I want! This probably indicates a coding problem in your app, there's nothing wrong in "re-installing" an app as long as your app can detect it was previously installed, there are many ways to do that (most of them involving communication with an external server)

Answer (score 0):

One solution that came to my mind is set a value on SharedPreferences, though it can be erased/modified on rooted devices, and check if it's not set to call a webservice with the DEVICE_ID and check if already exists on your database, if not, add it.

With that.. if the user uninstall the application, next time he/she install it the SharedPreferences values will not be set, so when you call your webservice you'll see that the application was installed before on that device.